# Retrieving and using a json associative array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I use jquery and ajax to retrieve a dynamically made array made in php, like so:

```
$json = array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {

    $json['item_'.$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

If I test the php file in browser, it outputs:

```
{"item_3":"Simon","item_1":"Miriam","item_2":"Shareen"}
```

So far so good. But how do I use that array in jquery?

I have this jquery ajax:

```
$.getJSON( "json.php", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And testing that page in browser, it put this in console:

```
Object {item_3: "Simon", item_1: "Miriam", item_2: "Shareen"}
```

And that's ok right? Or should item_x also be in quotes?

**Now, how do I USE that array in jquery?**

If I try console.log(data[0]) it puts *undefined*

Comment: javascript does not have associative arrays - this is a javascript object, properties are accessed with . `console.log(data.item_3);`

Comment: I'm not targeting item_3. I want to use the first key and value (array is randomly made)

Comment: @mowgli — There isn't a first key, objects are unordered.

Comment: hm. Maybe I should make each value-pair an array itself, in php.. that seemed to work some

Comment: May be your sever does not return an array of Objects. Plz check that.

Comment: @mowgli: You should make it an actual array then, not an "associative array" (in PHP). You don't seem to need the "item_N" key.

Comment: The item_X key is the database id for the image url related to NAME, so I need it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in comments, php associative arrays become javascript objects, which cant be accessed numericaly.

A solution would be to send an  array of objects instead:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {

    $json[]= ['key'=>'item_'.$row['id'] , 'value' => $row['name']];
}
```

the in js:

```
data[0].key;
data[0].value;
```

EDIT obviously key is a misleading name in this example, better to call it something else:

```
$json[]= ['id'=>'item_'.$row['id'] , 'value' => $row['name']];
//js
data[0].id;
```

Comment: Ah yes, got to try this.. Edit: Hmm, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: I had to edit it into: $json[] = ['key' => $row['id'] , 'value' => $row['name']]; There was missing surrounding brackets

Comment: Even better: $json[] = [$row['id'] => $row['name']]; I don't need to set id/value :) Edit: hm or maybe I do.. console.log(data[0][0]) is undefined, but data[0] works.. But I'm getting closer!

Comment: @mowgli thank, fixed missing bracket, and you do need to set them as property names if you want to access the value of both in js.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$.each()` to iterate through that object,

```
$.each(data,function(key,val){
  console.log(key,val);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz5HB/)

If you want to access it without iterating it then simply use `bracket notation`

```
data['item_3'] //Simon
```

Or directly access it like,

```
data.item_3 //Simon
```

---

Then convert it like an array as per your wish like this,

```
var obj = {"item_3":"Simon","item_1":"Miriam","item_2":"Shareen"};

var convertedArray = $.map(obj,function(val,key){
    var obj = {}; obj[val] = key;
    return obj;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz5HB/2/)

Comment: Yes, I also tried this. I worked.. but do I really need to use each for an array and re-make an array so I can use that? Let's say I want to use $("#mydiv").html(first_key_and_var_in_array);

Comment: @mowgli what are you trying to do..?

Comment: I'm trying to build a very simple content changer/slider.. It should just replace a div with content from first array key/value, then wait 5 seconds, then replace with next array set. Something like that

Comment: @mowgli Then declare a `counter` and increment it for every slide, and access the values like `data['item_'+counter]`

Comment: Yes, hmm.. But the item_xx can be any number. AND the array is in random order (on purpose)

Comment: I think I have to split it up into two arrays.. One for items, and one for names.. no?

Comment: Ah yes. I did something like this in php. Create array for each pair, right?